# Explanation for the approximation of the annulus for calculating the resistance with the skin-effect

Tags: electromagnetism, approximations

I am currently researching the skin effect within a wire for my project. In the Wikipedia entry for the skin effect, an approximation for the effective DC resistance is given. I understand the second approximation, but I cannot comprehend the first approximation for the cross-sectional area in the denominator.

$R\approx{{\ell \rho} \over {\pi (D-\delta) \delta}}\approx{{\ell \rho} \over {\pi D \delta}}$

Do you have an explanation or a source for an explanation for this approximation?
Wikipedia-Entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This equation appears to be written as $R=\rho\frac{l}{A}$ in the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance). I am not sure if this is valid or not in this case, but it is definitely a simple equation.

Comment: @HEMMI yes, i am wondering, how they can approximate A with the given denominator above. But thank you for your input